# How to mark function as pure function for clang-tidy

Tags: c, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy on my code base and I'm getting a lot of false positives from the following pattern

```
int *a;
if(config(some_value))
    a = value;
...
if(config(some_value))
    *a = other_value; // <-- deference of garbage value
```

the config function has it's value setup from a file on startup and isn't altered after. So All calls to config(some_value) return the same value.

Is there some way to mark the declaration of config() to clang that this is the case?

Comment: `int flag = config(some_value); if (flag)`? If this works, it would be a lot clearer to the reader.

Comment: I've used that method in a lot of the newer code, but there are 1000's of this pattern around the code, so I can't fix all of them. So I was kinda hoping I could tag the function somehow and remove the false positives.